# setting content-type in HttpHeaders to "application/json; format=pandas-records" in Java to call an API

Tags: http-headers, content-type

Trying to call an API and it requires to pass content-type as "application/json; format=pandas-records".
How can I pass it in HttpHeaders instance in Java. Because I cant find anything in MediaType for above given Content-Type.

I tried adding by making a string out of it like given below.

```
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; format=pandas-records");
```

But this is not working and I am getting below error.
500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR: [{"error_code": "MALFORMED_REQUEST", "message": "Failed to parse input as a Pandas DataFrame. Ensure that the input is a valid JSON-formatted Pandas DataFrame with the `records` orient produced using t... (2257 bytes)]

Comment: It seems like the header is working fine, but the data that you send is not in the correct format. Could you add the HTTP body to your question?

Comment: Thanks JANO

{
 "id": ["525531688"],
 "endDate": "2021-04-07",
}
@JANO : Please find above given data. Do I need to convert the data from JSON to Pandas dataframe in the input ? 

Because above given JSON is working in POSTMAN when I pass as an input.

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid. You have to remove the last comma.

Comment: sorry @JANO for that that's a typo. I tried with removing the comma also but same issue. It works in postman but when I try to trigger the API but creating request programmatically then its not working. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong but is API expecting input in Panda dataframe format and is it different compared to normal JSON ?

 { "id": ["525531688"], "endDate": "2021-04-07"}

Comment: The pandas dataframe format is still valid JSON, but the structure could be predefined. I think if your request works with Postman you make something wrong when generating the HTTP body with Java. Can you edit the question and add the code for generating the body? Also, is `{ "id": ["525531688"], "endDate": "2021-04-07"}` exactly what you send with Postman? If the API is publicly available, a link would help too.